# Accelerometer using ADXL345 for Earthquake Detection

Tags: arduino

Well, i want to ask if ADXL345 can be used to detect an Earthquake Occurrence based on its magnitude/intensity level. For more information, I want to used an accelerometer to create a Device that can detect the intensity/magnitude level of an Earthquake.

I have absolutely no experience in this field, but it looks useful and fascinating.

Questions are:

1. is this device able to detect medium scale earthquakes?
2. if yes, does anybody did it, available to share experiences?
3. if no to the previous, is there any guide which explains algorithms, calculations and mechanical plans?

Answer (score 0):

That sensor is not suitable. It has 13 bit resolution at +-16g full range. That gives you a sensitivity of 0.002g for the lsb. In order to detect an earthquake directly below you, you need approx. a few milli-g ([e.g. see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_ground_acceleration)), even less for earthquakes with an epicentre elsewhere.

You want a sensor which is much more sensitive by a factor of 100 and probably with more resolution (better ADC), too.

(And you should have been able to do this quick google-search analysis yourself ;) )

Comment: what accelerometer is suitable to detect an Earthquake? Is Adxl335 suitable than adxl345 ?

Comment: Look at their sensitivity... and compare that to expected values.

Answer (score 0):

Using accelerometers reading tells you nothing about the actual magnitude of the quake itself. It tells you the size of the quake at your location. Combining location and amplitude will give you a 'weighted' measurement, but that's still useless without a calibration curve. Without knowing what acceleration, at a certain distance, corresponds to what magnitude you will be unable to tell what the magnitude is. You can certainly conclude that your measured earthquake has a median amplitude of, say, 2000% of a non-earthquake reading, but you won't be able to turn it into a Richter measurement. To do that you'd need to take some data during earthquakes of known magnitude and then work out how acceleration, distance and magnitude are related for your device. You could alternatively use a scale like the Shindo (just Google it).